# Why are both sig and T.let required for Sorbet to type check?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I set my file as `typed: strict`, and set my `initialize` method to take an array of floats, but `srb tc` reported that I had to use a `T.let` assertion in the body of the method:

```
# typed: strict
class Point
  extend T::Sig

  sig { params(c: T::Array[Float]).returns(t::Array[Float]) }
  def initialize(c)
    @c = c
  end
end
```

Can’t Sorbet infer the type of `@c` from the signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As of 2019-12 this is no longer the case (see [PR #2230](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/2230)). Now this code is perfectly valid (note that constructors' signatures declare `void` as the return type):

```rb
# typed: strict
class Point
  extend T::Sig

  sig { params(c: T::Array[Float]).void }
  def initialize(c)
    @c = c # Sorbet knows that c is a `T::Array[Float]`, so it assigns that type to @c
  end
end
```

Previously:

This is a known limitation in Sorbet: "[Why do I need to repeat types from the constructor?](https://sorbet.org/docs/type-annotations#why-do-i-need-to-repeat-types-from-the-constructor)"

TL;DR:

> [Sorbet] cannot reuse static type knowledge in order to automatically determine the type of an instance or class variable.

It was also reported in [#1666 Seemingly unnecessary type annotation of instance variables](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/1666)